# How to store mathematical symbols and display them in android app project?

Tags: android

I m designing an android app that requires to store and display mathematical symbols, equation. Please help me ..
Thank you

Comment: can you show your efforts so we can help you with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yo need to use unicode entity codes. 
Have a look at this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html